# Different eslint rules based on file extension

Tags: javascript, eslint

Is it possible to have different rules applied to files based on their files extension? For example I have [test].spec.js test spec files residing along my source code, but I like to add rules that only apply to them only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it's not possible, unless you create multiple configuration files and run eslint with correct globs for each file type separately. However, there's an open PR here: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/pull/8081 to add this functionality.

Comment: Available since 4.1.0: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/releases/tag/v4.1.0

Comment: What should happen to this answer now?

Answer (score 69):

This was added. Example [from the docs](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files#configuration-based-on-glob-patterns):

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "quotes": [ 2, "double" ]
  },

  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [ "bin/*.js", "lib/*.js" ],
      "excludedFiles": "*.test.js",
      "rules": {
        "quotes": [ 2, "single" ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Effecitively you can supply globs and a set of rules that *override* the default rules for files that match each glob.

Comment: What I hate about this is that now, there is no way to share the rules.

Comment: Actually nvm, I figured out the way: You can just add a new object to the `overrides` section which includes all the file extensions, and then define your rules in this object

Comment: Doc link needs to be updated https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files#configuration-based-on-glob-patterns